# UITableViewCell Indentation with Dynamic UILabel Height

Tags: ios, ios7

I'm loading up a table view where each table cell has some left indentation (think message threads/replies) and also contains a label which is of dynamic height (the contents of the reply). I'm using AutoLayout so the `UILabel` sizes itself. In order to implement the indentation for each `UITableViewCell` I followed the advice of people here on SO to override `layoutSubviews` for my `UITableViewCell` so it looks like this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    float indentPoints = self.indentationLevel * self.indentationWidth;

    self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(indentPoints,
        self.contentView.frame.origin.y,
        self.contentView.frame.size.width - indentPoints,
        self.contentView.frame.size.height);
}
```

What's happening now though is sometimes the UILabel text will be cut-off at the bottom. It seems to me that the UILabel is working off the old frame size when calculating it's appropriate height and drawing itself (since it is dynamic) not the new frame size which has indentation - with indentation, there is less width available for the same text, so it should know it needs to be taller.

If I remove this indentation and comment out my override of `layoutSubviews` or if I put the call to `[super layoutSubviews]` at the end, rather than the beginning, the text is no longer cut-off, but I lose my indentation.

What I want is for my `UITableViewCell` to be indented appropriately and for my dynamic UILabel to recognise the new frame size and draw without any cut-off. I've tried putting in calls to `layoutIfNeeded` in various places for my `UILabel` without success.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to calculate the size of the UILabel up front using:

```
CGSize size = [str sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(label.bounds.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

The use that to size your cell.  May be better to do this in your tableview datasource heightForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Hi railwayparade, the problem with the text being cut-off is not actually related to the cell size. I can set the cell size to 1000 and the UILabel text will still abruptly cut-off.

Comment: @Neil, Do you have constraints to the top and bottom of the cell for the UILabel so it will expand with the cell? Also, do you have numberOfLines set to 0?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this problem has the same root cause as the following Stack Overflow post: [UILabel not wrapping text correctly sometimes (auto layout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513794/uilabel-not-wrapping-text-correctly-sometimes-auto-layout)

Using the accepted solution to this problem (setting preferredMaxLayoutWidth in layoutSubViews) resolved this issue for me.