# ios: text does not wrap correctly on iPhone 5S and earlier (4 inch and smaller devices)

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, adaptive-layout

I have a label that is supposed to wrap around. There are 4 constraints on it (top/bottom and leading/trailing - no other constraints). The label wraps around correctly on iPhone 6 i.e. 4.7" screen and iPhone 6 Plus i.e. 5.5" screen, But gets cut off on the right edge on 4" inch or smaller screen devices. Please see the screenshot below.

[image]

It's as if it thinks available width is more than actual device width. any ideas? (sorry can't post image inline because it requires at least 10 rep)

FWIW: Here are the constraints on the label (I am writing these in pseudo code because these are set in IB).

```
label.top = top margin
label.bottom = bottom margin
label.leading = leading margin
label.trailing = trailing margin
```

Comment: a.What is the earliest iOS you support? b.Is your label lines number in the Storyboard is 0? c.Did you try to do label.sizeToFit() after assigning the text?

Comment: I am not supporting anything lower than iOS 9.0. yes number of lines is set to 0. I don't think it's a sizeToFit issue because it's not displaying one long line of text. it's wrapping, but at wrong point.

Comment: @Quentin thanks for editing the image to be inline.

Comment: Try to delete the constraints and add them again but with the "Related to margin" option UN-checked

Comment: @MatanGold thanks, actually i have already tried that. doesn't help.

Comment: Try to justify your lable text. label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Justified. If this will not work can you post the constraints code or image for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the issue was, This `label` was in a cell of type `TextCell`, and here's what I was doing in `TextCell`'s `layoutSubviews` method:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    // ... snip ...

    self.text.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 375 // This is the offending line
}
```

Change `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` to a sane value (e.g. `CGRectGetWidth(self.label.frame)`) fixed it.

Please note that the above is a simplification of what the issue was, the point being **when you have issues with a self sizing label in Cocoa Touch, always check that `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` is being set to correct value**

Here's a related question (pointed me in the correct direction): [UILabel not wrapping text correctly sometimes (auto layout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513794/uilabel-not-wrapping-text-correctly-sometimes-auto-layout)

Answer (score 0):

In your main_storyboard go to the bottom panel and click the Compact sizes inspector(or whatever how its called)
and chose this one

[image]

try to remove there all the constrains and add them again