# Possible to dynamically build layout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, label, sizetofit

I have a view for a contact.  Based on the contact info the user provides, I would like to either include labels if the information is available, or not take up space if the information is not available to avoid a bunch of fields like tel: email: etc. that are blank,

The page is laid out in storyboard.  Is there a way to keep label from taking up space if empty or otherwise dynamically construct page?

I was thinking of `[label sizeToFit];` but this still seems to leave at least one line of empty space for the label.

Edit: Shows vertical constraint set to 10.f and 0.f.  The image is shrinking but not the space it occupied.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use auto-layout to move other views when a view is hidden?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065938/how-to-use-auto-layout-to-move-other-views-when-a-view-is-hidden)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use constraints for this.

Building programmatically an advanced layout is very complicated and error prone but using Auto-Layout options you can do this.

For example you have a UILabel and sometimes you want to remove it from layout. So you can make a reference to your height and width constraint of that UILabel and so change as below:

```
widthConstraint.constant  = 0.0f;
heightConstraint.constant = 0.0f;
```

Also you can keep the initial value in a property and use them when you want to add to Layout.

### ---Edited---

**For taking effect** you should call `[self needsUpdateConstraints];` after change of constraint.

Comment: How do you set the constraints for the label?

Comment: In Interface Builder you can use assistant editor mode (Interface Builder with VC) and option drag selected constraint to your code. So then manipulate it.

Comment: That is shrinking the visual but leaving blank space.  Is there a way to eliminate the blank space too so the whole view collapses.

Comment: I didn't got your problem but with right constraint assigning you can do everything. Can you send an image from your problem?

Comment: For example, I placed height constraint on image.  When I changed it to 0 in code, the image disappeared but the place where the image was remained.  Tried same thing with label.  I am not very familiar with constraints.

Comment: Thanks, Edited answer's content!

Comment: There is probably a different constraint I should be working with but placing a constraint on the visual element and then changing the height is not changing the space.

Comment: If your label of o: 's vertical positioning is related to image (eg. vertical spacing between them) then it should work. But if that labels position not related to picture, Then it's behaviour is correct.

O: 's Y position should be related to picture. If not you change it's vertical spacing.

Comment: Ok.  Marked answer correct.  Seems like I have to play with constraints so they are all linked up.

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting iOS9+, the solution to your problem is the Stack View. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/

Here you'll find a quick introduction: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-218/

It will handle all layout for you, based on what views you give or take form it.

Z.

Comment: This looks great but I am not targeting 9.