# Dynamically move a view to a new position in auto layout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uilabel

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` layout that looks like this. It has three labels.

[image]

**Label 2** is an optional one. It's not present in every cell. So I want to hide that and move the **Label 1** down a little to be center aligned with the **Label 3** when that happens.

[image]

Here are the constraints I've added for each label.

**Label 1**

[image]

**Label 2**

[image]

**Label 3**

[image]

Notice I have added an extra constraint, Align center to Y with the value of 0 to **Label 1** and have set its priority to 750. I figured if I remove the **Label 2**, that constraint with the lower priority will take its place and move down.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        if indexPath.row == 1 {
            cell.label2.removeFromSuperview()
            cell.updateConstraints()
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. **Label 2** is removed but **Label 1**'s position is still the same.

[image]

How can I accomplish what I'm after?

---

**Attempt #1**

As per Mr. T's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34418752/1077789) below, I added a top constraint to the **Label 1**. And then in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, I changed it's value.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath 

    indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        if indexPath.row == 1 {
            cell.label2.removeFromSuperview()
            cell.topConstraint.constant = cell.bounds.height / 2
            cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

        return cell
    }
```

But this didn't work either.

Comment: Have a try on `layoutIfNeeded`?

Comment: @zcui93 Just tried it. No change.

Comment: I've noticed that both `CentreY` constraints for Label 1 are targeted to `superview`, should 2nd one related to Label 2?

Comment: Where is the label placed ? In the cell contentview or in a custom uiview in cell ?

Comment: @Mr.T In the cell contentView.

Comment: try cell.contentView layoutifneeded

Comment: Aslo try calling cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded

Comment: pls look at this answer for proper ways to update the cell after changing the constraints http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this utilizing the new `active` property of `NSLayoutConstraint`s as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30101295/1077789).

I made an `IBOutlet` to the Align center Y constraint with the value -13. Removed the `weak` keyword from it.

Then in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, I'm simply toggling the value for the `active` property.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
        cell.label2.hidden = true
        cell.oldConstraint.active = false
    } else {
        cell.label2.hidden = false
        cell.oldConstraint.active = true
    }

    return cell
}
```

[image]

Comment: I still dont think this is a best solution to this. Since label has intrinsic size there should be a way to achive this only by setting label text to nil. Will check that tomorrow and come with an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to have an outlet for the top constraint for the label 1. And when you remove the label 2, update the top constraint for the label1 which is the container.height/2 Or Remove the top constraint and give the centerY constraint to the label 1. And do layout if needed, once you updated the constraints.

Comment: Just gave it a try. But it doesn't seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty much impressed the way you came so far as that would have been exactly the same steps i would have followed if i had to accomplish it :)

Now my suggestion:
remove an extra "Align center to Y with the value of 0 to Label 1" that you have added that is not serving any purpose :)

I can see you already have a align center to y with some offset i believe  -13 to label 1. Create an iboutlet for that :) let's say its name as centerLabel1Constraint :)

whenever you want to bring label 1 to center hide label 2 and set centerLabel1Constraint.constant = 0 and call [cell layoutIfNeeded]

That should do the job :)
Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this. It works but only partially. The problem is there's no way to determine the value for the constant for cells that do have Label 2 because once you set it to 0, it gets reused when the cells are reused.

Comment: you already know the constant value right??? I mean when you want to show label2 simply make it visible and set the value of centerLabel1Constraint.constant back to -13 and call [cell layoutifneeded]

Comment: In summary: your cell for row at indexpath looks like if(condition:show label2){centerLabel1Constraint.constant=-13; label2.Hidden=NO; [cell layoutIfNeeded]} else{{centerLabel1Constraint.constant=0;label2.Hidden=YES; [cell layoutIfNeeded]} Isn't it???? :)

Comment: The thing is I'm not comfortable hardcoding the value -13. Because these are cells are self-resizing ones. Anyway I figured out a way to do this. I posted it [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34421192/1077789). Thanks for the help.

Comment: hardcoding -13 will not make any difference buddy :) because it is always subtracted from the center to y value which gets calculated dynamically based on the heights of the cell :) So no matter what is the size of your cell it will always be shown 13 pixel above the vertically centered line :) thats the purpose apple has provided that constant concept :) anyway glad that you found your solution :)