# iOS - Dynamic TableView Cell Height with priority constraint

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

In my application, there will be a UIViewController containing a UITableView and multiple tableview cell.

I have already subclass my tableView cell and link all the UIView form the interface builder to the script.

For better performance I preload all the tableview cell into an array as the data source of the tableView in `ViewDidLoad()` and reload the tableview.

Also, I set the UITableViewCell have with priority constraint, which there will be some UIView will be removed using `removeFromSuperview()` when fulfilled some condition.

And here is the problem, the second priority constraint ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/18066138/4851812) did not load well. The removed UIView still appear and the height didn't update.

**EDIT: If the just put the cell init on the `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`. It success sometimes, but the performance is poor. So I preload the cell.**

Are there any method need to call like forcing the cell update the constraint or layout before passing the cell to the tableView?

Comment: don't remove it, just set it's frame height to zero.

Comment: i tried, the desired view did disappear but the height didn't update.

Comment: i finally set the constraint frame size to zero and make it!