# Setting a view to hidden causes frame adjustments

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working in a collection view where one of our cells is able to be collapsed or expanded with a button press. The original developer of this feature is gone, so I'm trying to understand what all is going on. From what I can tell, when the user presses the button, the following code gets called:

```
- (void)expandCell{
    [expandCollapseButton setTitle:@"-" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [textView setHidden:NO];
    isExpanded = YES;

    [self.delegate cellDidExpandCollapse];
}
```

Our collapse cell is virtually identical except we don't hide it, set the `isExpanded` variable to `NO` and set the title to be "+" instead of "-". The `cellDidExpandCollapse` delegate method simply calls an `updateCollection` method, which I've copied below.

```
- (void)updateCollection {
    [self.collection performBatchUpdates:nil completion:nil];
    [self.amountCell updateTable];
    [self.collection setNeedsLayout];
    [self.collection layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

And that's it. Yet, when `layoutIfNeeded` is called, the system sets the frame of the textView to have a different origin and a height of 0. I'm not sure why, from my understanding, a hidden view is still "present", it just has an alpha of 0. Since I'm not calling any frame updating logic on the textView when I hit the button, I'm not sure how the frame is actually being set.

Are there any properties of a collectionView or a view in general that you can set to have the frame collapse its height when its hidden? Or is there any other magic properties I should be looking into?

Edit: The views are not setup in a stack view, so it shouldn't be resizing, at least as far as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use Auto Layout on the cell? If so, the hidden view still participates in the layout. 
Please refer to this [How to use auto-layout to move other views when a view is hidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065938/how-to-use-auto-layout-to-move-other-views-when-a-view-is-hidden)