# Re-position uilabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilabel, constraints

I wanted the "number" & "status" to display on the left if there is not QRCode display (constraints has been set for image & labels.)

Result without QRCode:
[image].

The result with QRCode will be:
[image]

Comment: why its unavailable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use auto-layout to move other views when a view is hidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065938/how-to-use-auto-layout-to-move-other-views-when-a-view-is-hidden)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IT IS very easy just make width Constraint of QRcode  image, if QR code is not available than make widht constant = 0,

[image]

```
  @IBOutlet weak var width: NSLayoutConstraint!
    if (your condition)
    {
       width.constant = 0
    }
    else
    {
       width.constant = 30
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with a second pair of constraints attached to left side of a view.

Add outlets to that constraints and set constant value to desired offset(from code), if there is no QRCode View.

Another way is to add MoreThanOrEquel constraint to left side (e.g >= 10)
Than another constraint with constant value 10, but with lower priority.

When you remove QRCode view, it will destroy it constraints and constraints to left side will affects and move yours labels to left.

Answer (score 1):

You could make constraint for labels that way:

I.e. make constraint for image leading to left side + image width, both labels also have leading to left side. Then if there is no QR Code adjust labels leading constraints to value you need.

Or you could make both labels leading to image view and set the image view width constraint to 0.

[image: pic]

Answer (score 0):

This Problem  is very simple , can achieve using UIStackView  just making hide/Show.

For Ex: If QR-code is present show or else hide QR-Code.
Label (Number and status and image) will automatically get adjust. Following is the screen short for better understanding.

[image]

```
IBOutlet UIView *qr_view; // Image or View
```

Case 1 :QR Present

```
qr_view.hidden = NO;// Show
```

[image]

Case 2: QR Not Present

```
 qr_view.hidden = YES;// hide
```

[image]