# iOS Autolayout With UIScrollview error in iOS7 but not iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, autolayout

I use Xcode6.1 to create a controller that with a scrollview as subview,then add subviews to scrollview.It work fine in iOS8 but not iOS7.It show error :

> > *** Assertion failure in -[UIView layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UIView.m:8794

after search SO,this ["Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews" with UITableViewCell subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610783/auto-layout-still-required-after-executing-layoutsubviews-with-uitableviewcel) seem look alike with my problem,but not work for me . That make me double myself if me use Autolayout correctly. By look at [iOS Autolayout with UIScrollview: Why does content view of scroll view not fill the scroll view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843633/ios-autolayout-with-uiscrollview-why-does-content-view-of-scroll-view-not-fill/16843937#16843937) ,I create a test project whitch add flowed code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
UIScrollView* scrollView = [UIScrollView new];
scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

UIView* contentView = [UIView new];
contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[scrollView addSubview:contentView];

UILabel *randomLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
randomLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    randomLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width;
});
randomLabel.text = @"this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test this is a test ";
randomLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
randomLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[contentView addSubview:randomLabel];

NSDictionary* viewDict = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView, contentView, randomLabel);

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict]];

[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[contentView]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict]];
[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[contentView]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict]];

[contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[randomLabel]-|" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict]];
[contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[randomLabel]-|" options:0 metrics:0 views:viewDict]];

}
```

It work fine both in iOS8 and iOS7 with test project,but it crash in iOS
7  when I add that code to my project .Show that :

> > *** Assertion failure in -[UIView layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UIView.m:8794

What can I do to fix that and ensure it works for iOS 7 and 8?

## Update

I have a controller with autolayout was created by Xcode5.02 ,it work fine build with Xcode.02 but has the same error message when builded in iOS7 with Xcode6.1