# Expanding cards like Paper by Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to redo the Paper by Facebook card expansion feature. I am talk about this : http://blog.brianlovin.com/design-details-paper-by-facebook/#24
The example displayed in this example is not the best as the content doesn't change a lot from the tiny status to large status. And that's what i'm trying to understand.

I've found a github project that did it at 50%. https://gist.github.com/chroman/8847406
I started to work from this piece of code. Then changed it so that the HomeViewController instantiate and hold 5 different UIViewControllers. Then each story is given a UIView (instantiated by the UIViewControllers) to display. The scrolling, the expanding works. But i struggle to redraw the underlying objects with constraints and i'm not sure that's even possible.

Are the tiny cards and expanded cards the same UIView ?
Then it would mean underlying objects display under constraints.

Or are they 2 independent UIViews ?
That would mean expanding the tiny card launch the transition to a large version of the card.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks a lot, Pierrick

Comment: This would help: http://www.raywenderlich.com/96062/custom-view-controller-presentation-transitions-swift

Comment: It just didn't help. That's exactly what i was looking for. Thanks a lot @HMHero

Answer (score 0):

The link shared by @HMHero was great. Add this post about [AutoLayout with UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843633/ios-autolayout-with-uiscrollview-why-does-content-view-of-scroll-view-not-fill) and you're good to redo the Paper by Facebook expanding card effect.

Cheers!