# UILabel in nested view in UIScrollView gets compressed under autolayout even with 1000 content compression resistance

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uilabel, autolayout

If I throw together scenes consisting of either of the following two view hierarchies and constraints (easily done in InterfaceBuilder), then everything works as expected...

---

1)

- A full-screen `UIScrollView` (0 distance to all edges of the superview)
- Within the `UIScrollView`, a single `UILabel`, with `numberOfLines` set to `0`, with 100% width (0 distance leading and trailing constraints), with no height constraint, with enormous amounts of text (1000s of lines), and with top and bottom constraints with a constant of 0 (so that there should be 0 distance from the boundaries of the `UILabel` to the content view of the `UIScrollView`).

Behaviour is as expected: the `UILabel` gets sized to fit its contents, which forces the content view of the `UIScrollView` to expand to fit the text, making all the text scrollable.

---

2)

- A `UILabel` with `numberOfLines` equal to `0` within some `UIView` *innerView* within some `UIView` *outerView* such that:

  - The label's edges all have 0 distance from *innerView*'s edges (with priority 1000)
  - *innerView*'s edges all have 0 distance from *outerView*'s edges (with priority 1000)
  - *outerView*'s top, leading and trailing edges all have 0 distance from the superview (with priority 1000)
  - *outerView* has a height that is less than the full height of its superview, enforced either by a height constraint or a bottom-distance-to-superview constraint, but this final constraint has some lower priority - say, 600.

In this case the behaviour is again as expected: if the `UILabel`'s Content Compression Resistance Priority is greater than 600, *outerView*'s height gets increased to fit all the text, and if it's less, the label gets truncated.

---

However the following case does *not* work the way I would expect, despite appearing to me to be exactly analogous to the other two:

3)

- A full-screen `UIScrollView`, like the first case
- Within the `UIScrollView`, a `UIView` *innerView* whose edges all have 0 distance from the `UIScrollView`'s edges (like the second case).
- Within *innerView*, a `UILabel` with `numberOfLines` set to `0`, loads of text, and Content Compression Resistance Priority set to 1000.

My expectation, based upon the previous two test cases, is that the `UIScrollView`'s content view should resize to fit the text of the label. However, instead what happens is that the content view gets set to the size of the `UIScrollView`, as does *innerView*, and the `UIScrollView` is not scrollable.

Why am I getting this behaviour which is inconsistent with my previous two test cases, and how can I get working content compression resistance and have the intrinsic content size of my `UILabel` respected when I'm nesting it in a view within a `UIScrollView` under autolayout? I can't see any reason for autolayout to compress my `UILabel` in the third case when it is perfectly possible for it to *not* compress it and still satisfy all constraints in exactly the same way as it did in the first case.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. There seems to be a bug with apple, so multiline text requires a two-pass approach to layout correct and it all relies on the property preferredMaxLayoutWidth.

I ended up adding these two methods to the ScrollViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(adjustScrollContentSizeOnMainThread) withObject:nil    waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void)adjustScrollContentSizeOnMainThread
{
    self.myLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.myLabel.bounds.size.width;
}
```

I based my solution on this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13616052/2828256