# Trying to set auto constraint on label, failing on long text

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, pure-layout

I'm trying to display rows containing a thumbnail and a title.

It works great for short title strings, but for long strings, it breaks. Rather than expanding horizontally, I would prefer it to expand vertically. Checkout the screenshot below to see what happens when a long string is used. I'm using [PureLayout](https://github.com/PureLayout/PureLayout) to manage Auto Layout:

```
thumbnailView.autoSetDimensions(to:CGSize(width: 75, height: 75))
thumbnailView.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .leading, withInset: kLabelHorizontalInsets)
thumbnailView.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .top, withInset: kLabelVerticalInsets)
thumbnailView.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .bottom, withInset: kLabelVerticalInsets, relation: .greaterThanOrEqual)

titleLabel.autoPinEdge(.leading, to: .trailing, of: thumbnailView, withOffset: kLabelHorizontalInsets, relation: .lessThanOrEqual)
titleLabel.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .top, withInset: kLabelVerticalInsets)
titleLabel.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .trailing, withInset: kLabelHorizontalInsets)
titleLabel.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .bottom, withInset: kLabelVerticalInsets)
```

The appropriate settings on the UITextLabel are also set:

```
 titleLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
 titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
 titleLabel.textAlignment = .left
```

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks
[image: tableview screenshot]

Comment: Why are you using `.lessThanOrEqual` for the leading constraint of your label?

Comment: @Paulw11 I want there to be a minimum margin between the label and the thumbnail

Comment: Ok, but you don't want `.lessThanOrEqual`.  That says that the margin must be `kLabelHorizontalInsets` **or less**. -20 is less.  You just want the margin to be `kLabelHorizontalInsets` so remove the `relation` parameter

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to restrict top and bottom constraint. The UILabel will auto adjust the contentHeight. You can refer to `contentHuggingPriorityForAxis:` and `contentCompressionResistancePriorityForAxis:`. You can fix the center of label rather than the bottom and top.

Answer (score 0):

Found one possible solution: [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149733/ios-autolayout-issue-with-uilabels-in-a-resizing-parent-view)

Turns out `UILabel`'s `numberOfLines` property and Auto Layout don't play along nicely.